# Duplicate lines of code consecutively with Pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I am currently creating a script which has approximately 100 lines of code. Within PyCharm, I am interested in duplicating each line of code consecutively throughout the script. An example demonstrating the desired output is shown below.

```
# Current Code

print("Hello World")
print("I enjoy python")
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")

# Desired Output

print("Hello World")
print("Hello World")
print("Hello World")
print("I enjoy python")
print("I enjoy python")
print("I enjoy python")
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")
```

As this is only a sample with 3 original lines of code, I simply created duplicates of the code by copying and pasting each line. In projects which contain over 100 lines of code, this would be impractical. How can I do this in PyCharm without copying and pasting line by line?

-Thanks

Comment: You just want to copy lines ? CTRL+D at the beginning or end of the line you wanna copy will duplicate it. OR, you could write a python script to parse your python script line by line, and duplicate each line twice ? Is this what you're interested in ?

Comment: Why don't you write down this python file to another file . Write everything thrice.

Comment: or use a for loop to print it out and just copy and paste

Comment: Is a for-loop unacceptable or something?

Comment: @Xhattam I am interested in having the lines of code copy consecutively, not a simple copy and paste of the entire script below the original. With CTRL+D it just pastes a duplicate of  all of the highlighted code below.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it in PyCharm you can use regex replace:

`^(.*)$` replace by `$1\n$1\n$1`:

[image]

But if you wont to do it using python script you can do something like this:

```py
with open('input.py') as f_input:
    with open('output.py', 'w') as f_output:
        f_output.writelines(sum([[x] * 3 for x in f_input], []))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, with `test.py` being your input script:

```
x = [e.strip() for e in open("test.py", "r").readlines()]  # get lines, strip them of the '\n'
r = [(x[i]+'\n') * 3 for i in range(len(x))]               # multiply each line by three
with open("test_out.py", "w") as out:                      # open an output, writing mode
    out.write(''.join(r))                                  # join the lines, write to output 
    out.close()                                            # close the file (keep things clean)
```

Stripping each line of the '\n' (which might be there or not on the very last line) ensure the last line is always written properly, that is, not as

`print("Stack Overflow is amazing")print("Stack Overflow is amazing")print("Stack Overflow is amazing")`

but as

```
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")
print("Stack Overflow is amazing")
```

if the carriage return isn't there.

Don't forget to change the output filename to an actual path if you want your output file somewhere else !

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
# Using readlines() 
file1 = open('input_file.py', 'r') 
Lines = file1.readlines() 

# open a (new) file to write
outF = open("myNewFile.py", "w")

for line in Lines:
   i = 0
   while i < 3:
       outF.write(line)
       outf.write("\n")

outF.close()
```

This will create a new file with every line written 3 times. You could rename it later to whatever you want.